# PHP/MySQL - Count number of fields with given prefix

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to count the number of populated fields that have a given prefix?

e.g. I have a table of Q&As with multiple choice answers.  Sometimes a question has 3 answer options, sometimes there a 4 or 5.  Each answer is in a field such as `answer1_a`, `answer1_b`, `answer1_c`, etc, -- is there a way to identify how many of these fields have data (for a given record)?  I need this to determine how many multiple choice options to present in the HTML.

Perhaps using **mysql_num_fields** in some way?

thanks,
Geoff

Comment: use looping. either way you need to get the value of this fields, right? do your checking on the loop and dont display it if null or empty.

Comment: Can you post your table structure?

Answer (score 2):

Given your table structure, Kaii's answer is correct.

For the future I would suggest using a real relational model like this:

```
CREATE TABLE QUESTION(
  ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  QUESTION VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

INSERT INTO QUESTION VALUES(1, 'My first question');
INSERT INTO QUESTION VALUES(2, 'My second question');
INSERT INTO QUESTION VALUES(3, 'My third question');

CREATE TABLE ANSWER(
  ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  ID_QUESTION INTEGER NOT NULL,
  ANSWER VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (ID_QUESTION) REFERENCES QUESTION(ID)
);

INSERT INTO ANSWER VALUES (1, 1, 'First possible answer for question 1');
INSERT INTO ANSWER VALUES (2, 1, 'Second possible answer for question 1');
INSERT INTO ANSWER VALUES (3, 1, 'Third possible answer for question 1');
INSERT INTO ANSWER VALUES (4, 2, 'First possible answer for question 2');
INSERT INTO ANSWER VALUES (5, 2, 'Second possible answer for question 2');
INSERT INTO ANSWER VALUES (6, 3, 'First possible answer for question 3');
INSERT INTO ANSWER VALUES (7, 3, 'Second possible answer for question 3');
INSERT INTO ANSWER VALUES (8, 3, 'Third possible answer for question 3');
INSERT INTO ANSWER VALUES (9, 3, 'Fourth possible answer for question 3');

SELECT
  QUESTION.ID,
  COUNT(*) as NB_ANSWER
FROM QUESTION
INNER JOIN ANSWER ON QUESTION.ID = ANSWER.ID_QUESTION
GROUP BY QUESTION.ID
ORDER BY QUESTION.ID;
```

See it work here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0025a/3/0

Comment: +1 - May I also suggest `ALTER TABLE answer ADD COLUMN sequence INT NOT NULL; ALTER TABLE answer ADD UNIQUE (id_question, sequence);` (not syntactically correct but you get the point).

Answer (score 1):

To solve this in SQL you would have to list all field names explicitly .. Assuming your field values are set to `NULL` when no data is given, an SQL solution may look like this:

```
SELECT *, 
    ( answer1_a IS NOT NULL +
      answer1_b IS NOT NULL +
      answer1_c IS NOT NULL +
      answer1_d IS NOT NULL +
      answer1_e IS NOT NULL ) AS number_of_answers
FROM answers
```

A scalable approach (that grows automatically when you change the table structure e.g. to insert a new answer 'f') would be to do this kind of calculation in PHP:

```
<?php
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM answers");
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res) ) {
    $count = 0;
    foreach ( $row as $fieldname => $value ) {
        if ( strncmp($fieldname, 'answer1_', 8) === 0 &&
             $value !== NULL ) {
            $count++;
        }
    }
    $row['number_of_answers'] = $count;
    $resultset[] = $row;
}
print_r($resultset);
```

However, the PHP solution has the drawback that you can not easily use a `HAVING` or `WHERE` clause in your `SELECT` statement to find (for example) all questions that have 4 possible answers.

Comment: I don't think you would need the `SUM()`, just them added together should be fine if each row is a unique question.